# PHP DOMDocument Check if load() Is Valid

Tags: php, rss, domdocument

I am trying to load an RSS feed from my blog which I will then display on my home page. The PHP code I am using is:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://www.example.com/blog/feed');
```

However, sometimes my blog gets too busy and fails to return a valid feed, at which point I get:

```
DOMDocument::load(https://www.example.com/blog/feed): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed
```

How can I prevent getting that error so my script doesn't throw an exception? I'm looking for a way to check if the call to DOMDocument::load() is valid, e.g.:

```
if( $rss->load('https://www.example.com/blog/feed') ) {
    // Do something if call to load() is successful.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First get the XML, check that it's not empty, then load it into DOMDocument.

```
$xml = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/blog/feed');
if ($xml) {
    $rss->loadXML($xml);
} else {
    // report error
}
```